# Show Jasper Report when no data when use XML datasource NOT blank page

Tags: xml, web-applications, xpath, jasper-reports, ireport

I use a **Jasper** as a report engine (using **iReport**-4.0.0)
My datasource is **XML file datasource** and use **XPath** expression when filling the report
For example
Sample Data

```
<StudentList>
<Student>   
    <StdntCd>cd11</StdntCd>
    <StdntNm>ee11</StdntNm>
    <Schl>Schl11</Schl>
    <Cty>Cty11</Cty>
</Student>
<Student>   
    <StdntCd>cd22</StdntCd>
    <StdntNm>ee22</StdntNm>
    <Schl>Schl22</Schl>
    <Cty>Cty22</Cty>
</Student>
</StudentList>
```

And my XPath expression is that

```
/StudentList/Student
```

The issue happened when No data such that

```
<StudentList>

</StudentList>
```

My need to *show all section of the report without detail* (because there is no data)
Although i set "When No Data" property with "All Sections,No Detail"
But still not work
Note
No data is equivalent to the previous XML **NOT like that**

```
<StudentList>
 <Student></Student>
</StudentList>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "still not work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid this best is to define a `printWhenExpression` for the detail band.

in iReport: click in report inspector on detail band, in properties panel modify `printWhenExpression` to `$F{StdntCd} != null` : this will only show students that do have a code other than `null`.

If you utilize the `REPORT_COUNT` variable, you will need to add a custom variable instead:

- type: `java.lang.Integer`
- Calculation: `Sum`
- Expression: `$F{StdntCd} == null ? 0 : 1`
- Initial value: `0`

This will allow you all the time the correct output, assuming that the field `StdntCd` can never be `null` if valid data is provided.

If your report runs with a different language than groovy you might need to adjust the expressions.